# Filter values by provided input

Tags: javascript, regex

I try to fulfil the case when the input provided by the user filters the the list with values which can be either a word or number (both as strings).

Below are all described cases, but I wonder if there a way to combine all three cases verification into one. Good suggestion are much appreciated :)

```
Case 1: 1 === 1
Case 2: +1 === +1
Case 3: (+1) ==== (+1)
```

```js
const form = document.querySelector('input')

form.addEventListener('change', () => {
  console.clear()
  filterValues()
})

const values = {
  first: {code: "1", name: "one"},
  second: {code: "2", name: "two"},
  third: {code: "3", name: "three"},
  four: {code: "4", name: "four"},
  five: {code: "5", name: "five"}
}

function filterValues() {
  Object.keys(values).forEach(value => {
    const code = values[value].code
    const name = values[value].name
    const input = form.value
    
    const inputMatchesCode = code.indexOf(input.toLocaleLowerCase()) === 0
    
    /* Code case nr 1 */
    const inputMatchesName = name.indexOf(input.toLocaleLowerCase()) === 0
    
    /* Code case nr 2 */
    const dialingCode = `+${code}`
    const inputMatchesDialingCode = dialingCode.indexOf(input.toLocaleLowerCase()) === 0
    
    /* Code case nr 3 */
    const fullDialingCode = `(+${code})`
    const inputMatchesFullDialingCode = fullDialingCode.indexOf(input.toLocaleLowerCase()) === 0
    
    if (inputMatchesCode || inputMatchesName || inputMatchesDialingCode || inputMatchesFullDialingCode) {
      console.log(value)
    }
  })
}
```

```css
input {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" />
```

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to match the number (ie: 1) and the variations are expected to match your created strings (ie: "(+1)" ) - rather than trying to match all variations- why don't you simply remove the auxillary characters and compare only the numbers - ie (1 === 1 to give "First"). That way you dont have to account for the "(", "+" or ")" characters - if the number itself matches you can give the expected outcome.

I have used your code, but stripped out the alternate characters and the logic behind the different cases.

```js
const form = document.querySelector('input')

form.addEventListener('change', () => {
  console.clear()
  filterValues()
})

const values = {
  first: {code: "1", name: "one"},
  second: {code: "2", name: "two"},
  third: {code: "3", name: "three"},
  four: {code: "4", name: "four"},
  five: {code: "5", name: "five"}
}

function filterValues() {
  Object.keys(values).forEach(value => {
    const code = values[value].code
    const name = values[value].name
    const input = form.value.replace(/[\(\+\)]/g,'');
    
    const inputMatchesCode = code.indexOf(input.toLocaleLowerCase()) === 0

    const inputMatchesName = name.indexOf(input.toLocaleLowerCase()) === 0
    

    if (inputMatchesCode || inputMatchesName) {
      console.log(value)
    }
  })
}
```

```css
input {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" />
```

Comment: Thank you, gavgrif. All best solutions are indeed clean and look simple :)